# How correctly apply globalCompositeOperation on canvas's elements?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, globalcompositeoperation

I have an issue with **globalCompositeOperation**.

My goal is to make Blue element displayed only inside of Red element and should not be visible outside of Red rectangle at all (kind of Overflow-Hidden effect). Plus, both Red and Blue must have Transformation ability (both editable).

As you can see, if I'll add one more element into the canvas (yellow element), the Blue one become visible on the area where Yellow and Blue overlaps.

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/q4bvu0tb/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');


var yellow = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 200,
  left: 0,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'yellow'
});
canvas.add(yellow);


var red = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'red',
  rx: 40
});
canvas.add(red);


var blue = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 150,
  left: 80,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'blue',
    globalCompositeOperation: 'source-atop'
});
canvas.add(blue);



var green = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'green'
});
canvas.add(green);
```

Mandatory Conditions:

- Preserve elements appearance on Canvas.
- No clipping (since clipping
  does not allow to add background color and image in the same time)

Answer (score 3):

It could be accomplish-able using the following steps ...

- remove the `yellow` element before drawing the `blue` one
- after drawing the `blue` element set the `yellow` element's `globalCompositeOperation` to `destination-over` and add it back

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var yellow = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 200,
  left: 0,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'yellow'
});
canvas.add(yellow);

var red = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'red',
  rx: 40
});
canvas.add(red);

canvas.remove(yellow); //remove yellow

var blue = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 150,
  left: 80,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'blue',
  globalCompositeOperation: 'source-atop'
});
canvas.add(blue);

yellow.set({globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-over'}); //set gCO for yellow
canvas.add(yellow); //add yellow back

var green = new fabric.Circle({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  radius: 100,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'green'
});
canvas.add(green);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment... In this way it will, I know... The problem is that elements load dynamically to the canvas and I need to preserve they appearance (z-index). Yellow must be behind the Red area.

Comment: Very nice... could be a potential solution, however, that kind of manipulation with Removing and Adding elements breaks the condition of dynamic elements' rendering and, as a consequence, won't preserve their ordering...

Comment: Well.. after playing with "dynamic" rendering, I've realized that Removing elements and bring them back isn't a good idea because you never know what is an upcoming element and what element needs to be removed and then brought back... anyways...

Comment: Does this work when we add objects dynamically?